# Change column collate from utf8mb4_general_ci to utf8mb4_bin corrupt the table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

For somes reasons (needs accent sensitivity), we need to change the collation of a column from utf8mb4_general_ci to utf8mb4_bin on mysql database (mysql and mariadb). So we just execute this request:

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

This column has an unique index. And that work perfectly on multiple environnement but, and we don't know why, corrupt the data on some other (prod environment obviously...):

```
Corruption of an index tree: table `db`.`table` index `unique_column`, father ptr page no 640, child page no 683 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
```

Does anyone have any idea why ? We can't reproduce and prod environment is not the good place to test...
Maybe data problem because when we reimport a dump of this database, that work perfectly after but how to find this data problem ?

Thank you ! (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CONVERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

But still do **nothing without a backup**

Comment: That's convert all the table, and we prefer to modify only one column.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, we delete the unique index, change the collate and recreate the index. The problem is solved but we don't understand why we need to do that on few databases...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change just one column:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(512) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```